# Newtonsoft JSON.NET: get value on serialization error?

Tags: c#, json.net

I am upgrading a project from Newtonsoft.Json version 4 to version 6.

The project subscribes to the `Error` handler on the `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer` class, like so:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer _serializer = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer();
_serializer.Error += SerializerErrorHandler;

protected virtual void SerializerErrorHandler(object sender, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.ErrorEventArgs e)
{
    //handle error
}
```

In v4, when an error occurred, you could access the `MemberValue` property on the `ErrorContext` to get the value for the piece of JSON that generated the error:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken obj = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.Parse(e.ErrorContext.MemberValue.ToString());
```

In v6, the `MemberValue` property appears to be gone and I can't see any other way to get the JSON value that caused the error.

Is there a way in v6 to get hold of the current piece of JSON that is being parsed in the error handler?